Read xml file content chunk by chunk over http input stream and url decode each chunk

Download a url encoded xml file of 200MB size chunk by chunk
URL decode each chunk
Flush the url decoded xml chunk to a file.

In method downloadLineByLineIntoJVMemoryAndDecodeWholeContentAndWriteWholeContent i read the whole file line by line into a String and successfully url decoded into expected xml content.
In method downloadAndDecodeAndWriteLineByLine i got exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern
    at java.base/java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:236)
    at code.shubham.commons.utils.FileDownloadUtils.downloadAndDecodeAndWriteLineByLine(FileDownloadUtils.java:35)
    at code.shubham.commons.utils.FileDownloadUtils.main(FileDownloadUtils.java:67)

I do want to end up getting OutOfMemoryError by loading the whole file content of 200MB into memory as done in downloadLineByLineIntoJVMemoryAndDecodeWholeContentAndWriteWholeContent. The file size may increase in future.
What is the right way to achieve this chunk by chunk ?
package code.shubham.commons.utils;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class FileDownloadUtils {

    /**
     * Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern
     *  at java.base/java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:236)
     *  at code.shubham.commons.utils.FileDownloadUtils.download(FileDownloadUtils.java:25)
     *  at code.shubham.commons.utils.FileDownloadUtils.main(FileDownloadUtils.java:40)
     *
     * @param inputStream
     * @param downloadFilePath
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void downloadAndDecodeAndWriteLineByLine(InputStream inputStream, String downloadFilePath) throws IOException {
        Files.deleteIfExists(Path.of(downloadFilePath));
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
             FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadFilePath, true)) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                outputStream.write(URLDecoder.decode(line, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).getBytes());
                outputStream.write("\n".getBytes());
                outputStream.flush();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void downloadLineByLineIntoJVMemoryAndDecodeWholeContentAndWriteWholeContent(InputStream inputStream, String downloadFilePath) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));) {
            String line = null;
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(line);
            }
            String urlDecoded = URLDecoder.decode(content.toString());

            Path downloadPath = Path.of(downloadFilePath);
            Files.write(downloadPath, urlDecoded.getBytes());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String urlEncodedXML = "%3Ca%0\n" +
                "A%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fa%3E";
        String filePath = "/tmp/tst.xml";
        if (!Files.exists(Path.of(filePath)))
            Files.createFile(Path.of(filePath));
        Files.write(Path.of(filePath), urlEncodedXML.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);

        FileDownloadUtils.downloadLineByLineIntoJVMemoryAndDecodeWholeContentAndWriteWholeContent(
                new FileInputStream(filePath), "./downloadLineByLineIntoJVMemoryAndDecodeWholeContentAndWriteWholeContent_test.xml");

        FileDownloadUtils.downloadAndDecodeAndWriteLineByLine(
                new FileInputStream(filePath), "./downloadAndDecodeAndWriteLineByLine_test.xml");
    }

}


